# McEliece crytography Example

Tags: encryption, post-quantum-cryptography

Please could someone kindly give an example of McEliece cryptosystem with a detailed explanation, most especially, the decoding aspect

Comment: What have you read so far that wasn't detailed enough?  Have you read the documentation for the [Classic McEliece](https://classic.mceliece.org) submission to NIST PQC, or the [McBits paper](https://cr.yp.to/papers.html#mcbits) or its bibliography?

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I donot understand how the McEliece decryption works. Could i get a detailed explanation with example. Thanks